# One word for taking the first step

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that summarises the following scene:

Son tells his father that he loves him. Usually, dad has trouble expressing his emotions with words, so he is glad the son made the first step.

What did the son do for his father here - in one word.

Comment: "*I need a word that summarises the following scene*" - "Why? And what you need is an intransitive verb, e.g. "to start".

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. "

Comment: He accommodated his father, perhaps.

Comment: He *broke the ice*. Extra credit for three words where you preferred only one.

Answer (score 2):

He *broached* the subject or *started* or *opened* communications. Can hardly be a single word.